# Search-Mailbox for "private" emails

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I have need to search for emails in a shared mailbox and delete any that are flagged with the "private" flag.

After consulting the documentation 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd298173(v=exchg.150).aspx

However there is nothing relating to filtration by flag in the KQL query documentation.

Does anyone know what value i can query to identify messages with the "private" flag ?

Comment: What API and programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: i was using straight up power-shell thus far

Comment: Yes, PS is just a language. Were you using the Outlook Object Model (creating an instance of Outlook.Application object etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can do it with Search-Mailbox cmdlet.

But you can do it using EWS (exchange web services protocol).

Take the first part of this script to find private messages:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Clear-Private-Flag-on-3cac4d50